# $_REQUEST[] array is not present in phpinfo 

Tags: php, cookies

I'm not quite familiar with php and I wanted to ask upon what conditions `$_REQUEST[]` array-variable is not displayed when calling `phpinfo()`?

Even setting `variables_order` in `php.ini` with stndard `EGPCS` doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`COOKIE` environment variable being parsed and become a source for [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) array in PHP

Answer (score 1):

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web
>   server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any
>   of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Since we have no context it's gonna be a shot in the dark: what happens if you use the superglobal variable $_COOKIE[''] instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be set if the end-user is blocking cookies.  Also, it wouldn't be set if you were running your PHP script through the CLI.